# Let's create random number genrator

Tags: code-golf

The task is to make a function which returns random number, no build in functions allowed, returned value should be random or pseudo-random and no sequence allowed, no matter what the formula is and how scattered values are.

To simplify task, returned value should be 32-bit integer or float from range [0; 1)

It is code golf, shortest code wins :)

Answer (score 3):

## CoffeeScript (16 bytes)

```
->new Date%2**32
```

This is awful random number generator, but if you wait enough, you can get any integer.